# Call static method of inner class with object of outer class

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two classes. One is this:

```
namespace DataStructures_Algorithms
{
    public class BackendService
    {

        public class LocationServiceQueue
        {
            private static string deviceId;
            private static POI currentPOI;
            private static DateTime timeStamp;
            private static ConcurrentQueue<DeviceMessage> concurrentQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<DeviceMessage>();

            public static void Enqueue(DeviceMessage deviceMessage)
            {
                try
                {
                    concurrentQueue.Enqueue(deviceMessage);

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Exception Occured in LocationServiceQueue Class " + ex.ToString());
                }
            }

        }
}
```

and now i want to call enqueue method of LocationServiceQueue class.

```
                backendService.LocationServiceQueue.Enqueue(new DeviceMessage
                {
                    DeviceId = deviceID,
                    CurrentPOI = currentPOI,
                    Timestamp = DateTime.Now
                });
```

it gives an error that you cannot access. How can I access?

Comment: Could you show more on how you're calling it? For example, did you instantiate the class properly first?

Comment: i first instantiate the backedService object. `BackendService backendService = new BackendService();`. but now i am stuck how to call that static method of inner class of that backendService object

Comment: If the answer below doesn't work for you (it does seem correct though), I saw one of the answers online, they suggest passing your outer class as a parameter to the inner one. Maybe this can help: [Can i access outer class objects in inner class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2957900/can-i-access-outer-class-objects-in-inner-class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Enqueue` is a class method so you have to access method using class name (*not* using instance variable).

Since inner `LocationServiceQueue` class a public class, you could do this.

```
BackendService.LocationServiceQueue.Enqueue(new DeviceMessage
            {
                DeviceId = deviceID,
                CurrentPOI = currentPOI,
                Timestamp = DateTime.Now
            });
```

Comment: So is there any way that i access the inner `LocationServiceQueue` class by the object of `BackendService` classs?

Comment: No, not possible. If you want make it instance specific, make your `Enqueue` method not static and create a property/field for `LocationServiceQueue` class inside your `BackendService`.

Comment: thanxs a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

I posted a link in the comments, but an answer would be easier to help you with.
Modify your code to this:

```
namespace DataStructures_Algorithms
{
    public class BackendService
    {
        public class LocationServiceQueue
        {
            private BackendService _backendservice;

            private static string deviceId;
            private static POI currentPOI;
            private static DateTime timeStamp;
            private static ConcurrentQueue<DeviceMessage> concurrentQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<DeviceMessage>();

            public LocationServiceQueue(BackendService outer)
            {
                _backendservice = outer;
            }


            public static void Enqueue(DeviceMessage deviceMessage)
            {
                try
                {
                    concurrentQueue.Enqueue(deviceMessage);

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Exception Occured in LocationServiceQueue Class " + ex.ToString());
                }
            }

        }
}
```

And later:

```
BackendService.LocationServiceQueue l = new BackendService.LocationServiceQueue(new BackendService());
```

Although this only works if you don't really care about your BackendService class, but only about the LocationServiceQueue methods.