# Inner class and Outer class in c#

Tags: c#

how to implement inner outer classes in c#

i have two nested classes

like

```
class Outer
{
    int TestVariable = 0;
    class Inner
    {
        int InnerTestVariable = TestVariable // Need to access the variable "TestVariable" here
    }
}
```

Its showing error while compiling.

It can be solved by

1) Making TestVariable as static

2) Passing an instance of Outer class to Inner class

but in **java** there is no need to create Instance or static .

can i use the same functionality in C# too ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the best way of accessing the control in the enclosing class from the nested class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/185124/whats-the-best-way-of-accessing-the-control-in-the-enclosing-class-from-the-nes)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, C# does not have the same semantics as Java in this case. You can either make `TestVariable` `const`, `static`, or pass an instance of `Outer` to the constructor of `Inner` as you already noted.

Comment: I'm trying to access the private members of an Outer class from an Inner class that is nested within it, using a reference to an Outer instance, and I still get a CS1061 (".. does not contain a definition..").

Answer (score 3):

You can create an instance of inner class without even have outer class instance, what should happen in that case you think? That's why you can't use it

```
Outer.Inner iner = new Outer.Inner(); // what will be InnerTestVariable value in this case? There is no instance of Outer class, and TestVariable can exist only in instance of Outer
```

Here is one of the ways to do it

```
  class Outer
    {
        internal int TestVariable=0;
        internal class Inner
        {
            public Inner(int testVariable)
            {
                InnerTestVariable = testVariable;
            }
           int InnerTestVariable; //Need to access the variabe "TestVariable" here
        }
        internal Inner CreateInner()
        {
            return new Inner(TestVariable);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make variable `internal` or pass to inner's `constructor`

Comment: If i declare the variable as internal , it is not accessable inside the inner class

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No,

You will somehow need to inject the TestVariable into your Inner class. Making your testVariable could potentially lead to undesired behaviour. My sugestion would be to inject it via the constructor.