# Meaning of .this and .class in java

Tags: java

Let's say we have a class name Home. What is the difference between *Home.this* and *Home.class*? What do they refer to?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

**Home.this**

`Home.this` refers to the current instance of the `Home` class.

The formal term for this expression appears to be the [Qualified this](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.8.4), as referenced in Section 15.8.4 of the Java Language Specification.

In a simple class, saying `Home.this` and `this` will be equivalent. This expression is only used in cases where there is an inner class, and one needs to refer to the enclosing class.

For example:

```
class Hello {
  class World {
    public void doSomething() {
      Hello.this.doAnotherThing();
      // Here, "this" alone would refer to the instance of
      // the World class, so one needs to specify that the
      // instance of the Hello class is what is being
      // referred to.
    }
  }

  public void doAnotherThing() {
  }
}
```

**Home.class**

`Home.class` will return the representation of the `Home` class as a [`Class`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) object.

The formal term for this expression is the [class literal](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.8.2), as referenced in Section 15.8.2 of the Java Language Specification.

In most cases, this expression is used when one is using [reflection](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html), and needs a way to refer to the class itself rather than an instance of the class.

Comment: Is there any similar way to do this in C# also?

Comment: @MiladIrannejad Not like NestingClass.this. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/185144/1986241

Comment: What about `MainActivity.this` in Android programming?

Comment: @nn0p android is based on Java. So basic concept of Java also applied to Android. Above answer also for `MainActivity.this`

Answer (score 5):

`Home.class` returns the instance of `java.lang.Class<Home>` that corresponds to the class `Home`. This object allows you to reflect over the class (find out which methods and variables it has, what its parent class is etc.) and to create instances of the class.

`Home.this` is only meaningful if you're inside a nested class of Home. Here `Home.this` will return the object of class `Home` that the object of the nested class is nested in.