# How do you interact with an Android activity from within a Firebase reference?

Tags: android, firebase

I want my code to do as follows:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    ...
    Firebase ref = new Firebase('url')
    ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // if one of the children fullfills a certain condition
            // throw a toast
            }
    }
}
```

The only problem is that I can't throw a toast because I am not within the context of the function.

How can I work around this?

Comment: This works fine for me `Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "this is my Toast message!!! =)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`. What problem are you having?

Comment: Excellent, it worked! Just a question - I know what 'this' does, but I have never seen the use of 'this' after a class (as in MainActivity.this). What does it do?

Comment: Also, let's say I have a variable before the ref variable. How do I change the value of that variable within onDataChange?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434041/meaning-of-this-and-class-in-java