# this@MainActivity vs MainActivity@this in kotlin

Tags: android, android-activity, kotlin, start-activity

As you may see that

**this@MainActivity** or **MainActivity@this**

is valid while starting activity in kotlin. I tried to find out answer but I did not found anything. Can anyone know about exact difference of it and which one valid ? Why it allowed both ?

Comment: `MainActivity@this` not valid in my side

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [Kotlin's Grammar documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/grammar.html#labelReference),

MainActivity@this is just a label for `this` with the name "MainActivity". You can set whatever label you want.

this@MainActivity is an actual reference of `this` from MainActivity

Hope I make it clear.

Comment: Thank you. Intent(this@MainActivity, SettingActivity::class.java) and Intent(MainActivity@this, SettingActivity::class.java) both are valid and working fine. Is there any reason or what statement is same as MainActivity.class and this within MainActivity.

Comment: You might want to read about it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434041/meaning-of-this-and-class-in-java?lq=1

Answer (score 4):

`this@MainActivity` - it is a reference to current `MainActivity` instance.

`MainActivity@this` - it is definition of a name of the label, i.e. **MainActivity**.

[More info about labels](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/returns.html#break-and-continue-labels).