# How to give internal class access to outer class properties

Tags: c#, inheritance, nested-class

So, this may be an issue of what should be child of what, but I am having difficulty figuring out the best way to perform the following.

Say I have a kitchen, and I want to issue a command to turn on my toaster, so I would call something like this in a button click event:

```
private void buttonToaster_On_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   myKitchen.Toaster.Activate();
}
```

I envisioned doing what is depicted below.  However, in C# it says that I have to make the RelayBoard "myStuff" a static.  If for some reason I wanted to control multiple kitchens with this, I would prefer to not make this static, but how would I make it so I can instantiate a kitchen, have one relayboard that talks to everything in it, and create appliances under that kitchen that access the RelayBoard "myStuff" to write the command to?

```
class Kitchen
{
  RelayBoard myStuff = new RelayBoard();

  Appliance Toaster = new Appliance();
  Appliance Coffee_Maker = new Appliance();


  class Appliance
  {
     void Activate()
     {
        myStuff.WriteCommand(ApplianceAddress, 1);
     }

     void Deactivate()
     {
        myStuff.WriteCommand(ApplianceAddress, 0);
     }
  }

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the best way of accessing the control in the enclosing class from the nested class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/185124/whats-the-best-way-of-accessing-the-control-in-the-enclosing-class-from-the-nes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply pass it a reference to the kitchen object:

```
class Appliance
{
  private Kitchen _parent;
  public Appliance(Kitchen parent) { _parent = parent; }
  void Activate()
  {
    _parent.myStuff.WriteCommand(ApplianceAddress, 1);
  }

  void Deactivate()
  {
    _parent.myStuff.WriteCommand(ApplianceAddress, 0);
  }
}
```

Comment: That is one thing that I saw as a possibility, but I was worried it would instantiate multiple Kitchens (one for each appliance).  Also the idea of creating an instance of the outer class inside the nested class just seems like trying to suck up a vacuum cleaner with itself.  Will this only reference the main Kitchen, or will it make multiple copies of Kitchens inside each appliance?

Comment: @Xantham: Don't create new instances of the outer class. Just pass in the reference of the outer class. Toaster = new Appliance(this);